# How to determine if we need to wait for ajax result to show in front end

Tags: javascript, ajax, frontend

In web app developing, some features need to modify database by ajax and need to show modified result on front-end as well. 
For example, modifying page title in front-end by ajax. I always hesitate to decide in these two options:

1. Front-end send ajax to modify pageTitle, and waiting for the ajax result. Then show results after get ajax result.
2. Front end show expected results first with javascript, then send ajax. Check result after ajax return, if success, do nothing, other wise report error.

The first option is more reliable while the second can give better user experience.

Any idea? Or any article talking about this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Seems like a judgement call and probably comes down to your requirements. Personally, I tend to do #1 for simplicity but have done #2 now and then. I'm going to vote to close as there's no definitive answer, just opinion.

Comment: If you know what the user will be saving is valid, then you could display the result right away and then save. But if you need to do any validation i would wait for the ajax call to come back and then display. I feel as long as you give the user some feedback as soon as they click neither would be a bad user experience.

Comment: Option 1 is also will be ok as long you don't block user doing something else while you save the data.

Comment: #2, which is just as reliable as #1 if implemented properly, but provides much better user experience

Comment: @Shan Robertson if we have validation items that need to check exist data in database, then waiting for ajax result is inevitable. Other wise, just want to let user feel as awesome as using a local app.

Comment: @Basic First stackoverflow question for me. Just want to hear some detail idea about how to determine, and what people mostly do. It's fine to close since I have heared some useful opinion from comments. Thanks.

Comment: @jallen0927 In that case, welcome to SO. For your reference, only mods (those with a diamond next to their names) can insta-close a question. For the rest of us, it takes 5 votes. So far I'm the only vote so it looks like general consensus is against me (at least so far). In any case, hope to see you around in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the first variant you mentioned is the most popular, the second one you described is also being widely used in the web and, in UX-terms, it is known as an "optimistic action" - the best example being Facebook "Like" button.

Unless you have a very good reason to implement an optimistic action, go with the "wait for the server response" method as it is the most reliable one, which may be extremely important in some cases and not so importand in others. The only benefit from using second option is a very slight user satisfaction improvement that may be the case when we talk about huge websites that utilize such feeature a lot (like social websites) but is probably irrelevant in most projects.

Also, waiting a short ammount of time for an action to complete is something users are prepared for and perfectly happy with. So I would say, unless you really need, want, and can afford using optimistic action go with the callback method.

To maintain the best user experience while making user wait it is good to show some loading indicator to them. You can controll it localy using $ajax callback faunctions or [jQuery Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/). But if you have a lot of such operations you can develop a global loader that will fire every time an asynchronous request is made - use [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) for that, here's an example:

```
// make a loading div and position it fixed with high z-index
// attach it to $loader varaible
var $loader = $('#loader');
$(document)
  .ajaxStart(function () {
    $loader.fadeIn();
  })
  .ajaxStop(function () {
    $loader.fadeOut();
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @bwitkowicz, your answer is very detail